# How to connect MySQL Database to Java desktop application throwing phpmyadmin?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, phpmyadmin

What's wrong with that i want to make login system for customers inculding the serial number

my code

```
                String username = "root";
                String password = "";
                
                try {
                    Connection MyConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", username, password);
                    Statement MyStatement = MyConnection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet MyResult = MyStatement.executeQuery("select * from data_center");
                    while(MyResult.next()) {
                        System.out.println("Connection success!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception exc){
                     System.out.println("Connection error!");
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
```

database name : database 
table name " data_center

including 6 fields 
id, username, password, license, published, expiration

Comment: Stack trace is ..?

Comment: can't understand you

Comment: Was there an exception? What was the output?